# Why do galaxies in the Local Group not obey the Hubble law?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, galaxies

The way I understand it is that the galaxies in the Local Group have a gravitational attraction that causes a relative velocity inconsistent with the recessional velocity predicted in the Hubble law. Is this a correct interpretation?

I'm not after an all too in-depth answer, mainly just a qualitative explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the recession velocity predicted by the hubble law is negligible at the local group, even if gravity among them could be absent. Their gravitational attraction though, is hard enough to keep them bound together.

Answer (score 1):

The [raisin bread](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/hubble.html) analogy can be used to help in understanding this too:

[image: raisin bread]

Dough is much more expandable than the raisin material. Raisins will expand a bit due to the heat and the pull from the dough stuck on their surface, but it is the dough that is moving. The forces that are holding the raisin together are much stronger than the force expanding the bread.

The gravitational forces holding our planetary system are stronger than the expansion, the gravitational forces holding our galaxy together also. But it is also true of clusters of galaxies, they retain their correlations; even though space is expanding  the rate is much weaker than the contraction of distances induced by the gravitational attraction.